# istio loadbalance service entry with active health check

Tags: ip, istio, fqdn

Is it possible to set up Service Entries pointing to 2 `fqdn` or `ip` address and have istio load balance it while checking active health of individual `ip`/`fqdn` external services?

There is outlier detection but that can lead to some negative if we can't control some endpoint `/my/custom/health`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this idea of having service entries (accompanied with WorkloadEntry) equipped with HealthCheck probe was abandoned some time ago. Check [this closed PR on github](https://github.com/istio/istio/pull/28347).

As a alternative, if you have direct control of hosts/servers, where externally to your service mesh workloads are running, you may try to use Auto-Registered WorkloadEntries (these support ReadinessProbes).
Check [this guide](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/virtual-machine/) how to accomplish it.